# Please How can I send my login form data to my email address with sketchware

Tags: javascript, php, forms, android-studio, sketchware

I created a sketchware app with form and login. So I want to send my login form to my mail and am having issues with that. Ive tried using the intent function and I dont know how to use the firebase option to host my database

Answer (score 0):

Using Intent, set data :yourmail@here.com, you can send data via email.